# how to pass key-value pair into a user-defined table type?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

**How do I pass a Dictionary or any other tuple type into a stored procedure?**

The stored procedure is defined as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Components]
(
  @OrderTypeID INT = NULL,
  @OrderTypeKey VARCHAR(40) = NULL,
  @SegmentID INT = NULL,
  @SegmentKey VARCHAR(40) = NULL,
  @FilterPairs KeyValuePair READONLY
)
AS 
BEGIN
..
```

Where `KeyValuePair` is defined as:

[image]

This is how I am calling the sproc:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<EntityType>(
    @"declare param1 int = --some logic
      declare param2 varchar = --some logic
      EXEC Components @param1=@param1,@param2=@param2"
);
```

**How do I pass a Dictionary or any other tuple type into a stored procedure for a user-defined table-type parameter?**

Please note that I do not want to use [`SqlParameter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) for this implementation if possible.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46711751/1236044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you tag the question *Entity Framework*, I assume you have a `DbContext`.

This `DbContext` represents (the access to) your database. It has DbSets for all tables in the database. It knows the relations between the tables, and it should also know how to call the stored procedures.

After all, should a user of the dbContext need to do something very different when calling a stored procedure than when handling a table?

Therefore the call to your stored procedure ought to be a function in your DbCntext

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<...> Table1 {get; set;}
    public DbSet<...> Table2 {get; set;}

    #region stored procedures
    public void Components(int orderTypeId, string orderTypeKey, ...
         KeyValuePair<string, string> pair, ...)
    {
        // TODO: fill code
    }
}
```

Change your stored procedure. @FilterPairs should be two parameters:

```
@FilterKey,
@FilterValue,
```

Now it will be easy to implement procedure Components:

```
public void Components(int orderTypeId, string orderTypeKey, ...
    KeyValuePair<string, string> pair, ...)
{
    object[] functionParameters = new object[]
    {
        new SqlParameter(@"OrderTypeId", orderTypeId),
        new SqlParameter(@"OrderTypeKey", orderTypeKey),
        ...
        // The KeyValuePair: in your store procedure two parameters:
        new SqlParameter(@"FilterKey", pair.Key),
        new SqlParameter(@"FilterValue", pair.Value),
    };
    const string sqlCommans = @"Exec ...
        @OrderTypeId, @OrderTypeKey, ...
        @FilterKey, @FilterValue, ...";
    this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlComman, functionParameters);
}
```

You'll know what to do if you want a function that takes a Dictionary, or any other class that implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

Comment: They've set up their procedure to receive a table-valued parameter. The implication being that they should be able to pass 0, 1 or *multiple* key/value pairs in a *single* call of the stored procedure.

Comment: thanks so much, @harald, this is extremely helpful. is this possible to do with a table-valued parameter? regardless, i'll be using your helpful answer in a separate project

Comment: I'm not sure what a table-valued parameter is in this context. Is this a row from a table that you want to use as parameter of the procedure? Of course instead of all separate parameters you could pass an object. I don't think you can pass objects as parameters to stored procedure, you'll have to do this using the SqlParameter. On the other hand, the advantage is that this way you hide that you are using a stored procedure, and in future you could change it to a different procedure, or a non-stored procedure., which enhances reusability in a different database