# EF: When executing a command, parameters must be exclusively database parameters or values

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

When executing stored procedure without return value but with a user-defined table type like this:

```
var dbStrings = new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.Structured)
{
    TypeName = new StringListType().Name,
    Value = new StringListType().DataRecordsFrom(listOfStrings.Select(p => p.Value).ToList())
 };
_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec [dbo].[InsertRecords] @SID, @filerType, @data", sid.ToString(), "Field", dbStrings);
```

I get an error

> When executing a command, parameters must be exclusively database parameters or values

How can I execute stored procedure through `DbContext` with multiple input parameters (some UDTT)?

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46711751/1236044

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need to (*as error message tells you*) create an array of `SqlParameter` and pass this when calling `ExecuteSqlCommand`.

```
var sqlParams = new SqlParameter[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@SID", sid.ToString()),
    new SqlParameter("@filterType", "Pin"),
    new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.Structured)
    {
        TypeName = new StringListType().Name,
        Value = new StringListType().DataRecordsFrom(listOfStrings.Select(p => p.Value).ToList())
    }
};

_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec [dbo].[InsertRecords] @SID, @filterType, @data", sqlParams);
```